# Changing a boolean value with a button in django

Tags: html, django, python-3.x

I have 2 buttons accept and decline in my requests.html when ever accept is clicked the request_status in my database should change to True and when decline is clicked it should change to False. My problem is that nothing happens when either of these two buttons are clicked.I am using query strings to retrieve the the wanted column from the database.

views.py:

```
def requests_leave_days(request, **kwargs):
if request.method == 'POST':
    leaving_request = TimeOffRequest.objects.get(id=kwargs['request_id'])

    if 'accept_request' in request.POST:
        leaving_request.request_status = True
        leaving_request.save()



count = {'accepted': 0, 'declined': 0, 'pending': 0}
accepted = TimeOffRequest.objects.all().filter(request_status='True')
refused =  TimeOffRequest.objects.all().filter(request_status='False')
pending =  TimeOffRequest.objects.all().filter(request_status=None)

#counting the number of refusals, acceptions and pending in the database
for acceptions in accepted:
    count['accepted'] += 1

for refusal in refused:
    count['declined'] += 1

for pending in pending:
    count['pending'] += 1

return request.user.is_manager(
    render(request, 'managers/requests.html', 
          { 'accepted' : accepted,
            'declined' : refused,
            'pending' : pending,
            'employees': User.objects.all(),
            'workingperiods' : WorkPeriod.objects.all(),
            'count' : count}),
    redirect('news')
)
```

requets.html:

```
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-profile-tab">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th scope="col">ID</th>
                          <th scope="col">Naam</th>
                          <th scope="col">E-mail</th>
                          <th scope="col">Telefoonnummer</th>

                          <th scope="col">Datum</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                          {% for requests in pending %}
                              {% for employee in employees %}
                                  {% if requests.user_id == employee.id %}
                                      <tr>
                                          <th scope="row">{{ employee.id }}</th>
                                          <td>
                                              {{ employee.first_name | title }}
                                          </td>
                                          <td>{{ employee.email }}</td>
                                          {% if employee.phone_number == None %}
                                              <td>Geen</td>
                                          {% else %}
                                              <td>{{ employee.phone_number }}</td>
                                          {% endif %}

                                          {% for workday in workingperiods %}
                                              {% if workday.id == requests.id %}
                                                  <td>{{ workday.start_time |date:"d F, Y"|lower }} - {{ workday.end_time |date:"d F, Y"|lower  }}</td>
                                              {% endif %}
                                          {% endfor %}
                                          <td><a href="{% url "requests" request_id=requests.id %}"><button method="POST"  type="submit"  name="accept_request"  class="btn btn-dark" style="color: green;">Accepteren</button></a></td>
                                          <td><a href="{% url "requests" request_id=requests.id %}"><button name="decline_request" type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="color: red;">Weigeren</button></a></td>

                                      </tr>
                                  {% endif %}

                              {% endfor %}

                          {% endfor %}
                      </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be done with AJAX? Currently you just have a button in a link (`<a>`) which will perform a GET request, you need to have these as buttons in a `<form method="post'>` to submit the data as a POST

Comment: How can I use <form method="post'> along with the following code: "{% url "requests" request_id=requests.id %}"

Comment: `<form method="post' action="{% url "requests" request_id=requests.id %}">`

Comment: You know you can use [`count()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#count) to count the number of items in a queryset? Looping through the objects and doing `+= 1` is grossly inefficient. Or if you need all the objects anyway, then do `len(accepted)` to get your count.